# Postgresql join only most specific cidr match

Tags: postgresql, join, cidr

I have a table "test_networks" that is a list of networks with a description about what each network is and where it is located.

```
CREATE TABLE test_networks
(
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  address cidr,
  description text
);
```

The field "address" will be any of the following:

- 10.0.0.0/8
- 10.1.0.0/16
- 10.1.1.0/24
- 10.2.0.0/16
- 10.3.0.0/16
- 10.3.1.0/24
- 10.3.2.0/24
- 10.3.3.0/24
- 10.15.1.0/24
- 10.15.2.0/24
- 10.15.3.0/24

I also have a table "test_systems" which contains a list of systems and their properties (I have a few more properties, but those are irrelevant):

```
CREATE TABLE test_systems
(
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  address inet,
  owner text
);
```

Lets assume I have systems with the following addresses:

- 10.1.1.1
- 10.2.0.1

I want to create a report of all systems and their closest *networks* description (or empty description if no network is found). As you can see, 10.1.1.1 matches multiple networks, so I only want to list the most specific one (i.e. the one with the highest masklen()) for each system. Example output would be:

```
  hostaddr |   netaddr   |  description
 ----------+-------------+----------------
  10.1.1.1 | 10.1.1.0/24 | third network
  10.2.0.1 | 10.2.0.0/16 | 4th network
```

I tried using this query:

```
SELECT s.address AS hostaddr, n.address AS netaddr, n.description AS description
FROM test_systems s
LEFT JOIN test_networks n
ON s.address << n.address;
```

However, this will give me a list of all system + network pairs, e.g.:

```
 hostaddr |   netaddr   |  description
----------+-------------+----------------
 10.1.1.1 | 10.0.0.0/8  | first network
 10.1.1.1 | 10.1.0.0/16 | second network
 10.1.1.1 | 10.1.1.0/24 | third network
 10.2.0.1 | 10.0.0.0/8  | first network
 10.2.0.1 | 10.2.0.0/16 | 4th network
```

Does anyone know how I can query for only the most specific network for each system?

Comment: Just FYI, `PRIMARY KEY` implies `NOT NULL`.  You don't need to specify `NOT NULL` for primary keys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the "top n in group" query, where n = 1 in this case.  You can do this using the `row_number()` window function:

```
SELECT x.hostaddr, x.netaddr, x.description FROM (
  SELECT
      s.address AS hostaddr,
      n.address AS netaddr,
      n.description AS description,
      row_number() OVER (
          PARTITION BY s.address
          ORDER BY masklen(n.address) DESC
      ) AS row
  FROM test_systems s
  LEFT JOIN test_networks n
  ON s.address << n.address
) x
WHERE x.row = 1;
```

Comment: This does _exactly_ what I need. I spent all day trying to figure this out on my own, but failed. Care to explain what is happening here?

Comment: @invictus If you add `x.row` to the columns selected by the outer query, it should be a bit more obvious.  The window function `row_number()` numbers all rows in the result set starting from 1.  `PARTITION BY s.address` means that each distinct value of `s.address` has its own set of row numbers, starting from 1, and the `ORDER BY` clause means that the one that has the largest `masklen(n.address)` will receive the value 1.  So from there we just have to filter out the rows that don't have a `row_number()` of 1, which is what the outer `SELECT` does.

Comment: Cool. Is it possible to use any specific indexes to make this go faster?

Comment: An index on `netaddr` could potentially speed up the ordering, but I woudn't know without a large data set to test on.  (The planner is always going to decide that a seq scan is the best option with the small data set I used.)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT distinct on (s.address)
    s.address AS hostaddr,
    n.address AS netaddr,
    n.description AS description
FROM
    test_systems s
    LEFT JOIN
    test_networks n ON s.address << n.address
order by s.address, masklen(n.address) desc
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. What would be the advantage/disadvantage of this solution over the one provided above?

Comment: @invictus I think it is simpler. Run `explain analize` on both and check which is the fastest.